# How to get app name in Window 8 & 8.1 apps from a library?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have 2 projects named "Sample" (Store App), and "SampleLib" (Store Library). I wanted to get the name of the running app when I call it from Sample.csproj.

I wanted to get app name based on what version of OS it is:

in 8.0:

```
            // Get the assembly with Reflection:
            Assembly assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

            // Get the custom attribute informations:
            var titleAttribute = assembly.CustomAttributes.Where(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();

            // Now get the string value contained in the constructor:
            return titleAttribute.ConstructorArguments[0].Value.ToString();
```

in 8.1:

```
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.DisplayName
```

But can I conditionally do it when I set target framework on Lib project as 8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two projects, one for 8 and one for 8.1, and define a custom compiler constant that will conditionally compile depending on what you set for the value.

Comment: Do I need to bundle 1 dll or 1 dll for each platform?

Comment: 1 Dll for each platform, I believe.